# Show that $\hat x$ is a least squares solution of the system $Ax=b$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, least-squares, transpose

> Show that if $$\begin{bmatrix}A & I \\ O & A^T\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}\hat x \\ r\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}b \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$ then $\hat x$ is a least squares solution of the system $Ax = b$ and $r$ is the residual vector.

The wording of the problem is confusing to me, because I can usually find the least squares solution by finding the solution of $\hat x$ to $A^TA\hat x = A^Tb$. Except, this wants me to prove the least squares solution *is* $\hat x$, which doesn't make much sense to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the matrix:

$\begin{bmatrix}A & I \\ O & A^T\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}\hat x \\ r\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}b \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$

Allows us to generate the equations:

$A\hat{x} + r = b$ and $A^Tr = 0$

So, solving for $r$, we can show that this is the residual vector: $r = b - A\hat{x}$

And plug this into the second equation:

$$A^Tr = A^T(b - A\hat{x}) = A^Tb - A^TA\hat{x}$$

So if $\hat{x}$ is in fact the least squares solution to $Ax=b$, we have that:

$A^Tb - A^Tb$ which equals $0$.

So $\hat{x}$ is a solution to the normal equations and hence is the least squares solution to $Ax=b$.

Day is the best!

Comment: Least squares tries to minimize residual vector?

Comment: @Jack Bauer: Least squares: 'Least' implies minimization of the sum of the 'squares' of the residual errors.